# -fx-background-color for confirmation dialog box's OK button doesn't work if it's a variable

Tags: css, javafx

a.css:

```
.dialog-pane .button { 
    -fx-background-color: -fx-base; -fx-text-fill: white; 
}
```

Code:

```
Alert confirmationDialog = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION); 
confirmationDialog.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add("a.css");
```

When I open the confirmation dialog, the Cancel button is styled correctly, but the OK button is not. However, if I change -fx-background-color to an actual color, like:

```
.dialog-pane .button { 
    -fx-background-color: red; -fx-text-fill: white; 
}
```

Both buttons will be styled correctly. I've been googling for a while and I'm stumped. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Are you talking about the color of the OK button (the default button)?

Comment: Yes. Using a custom color variable is not working on the OK / default button, but does work on Cancel.

Answer (score 0):

The default stylesheet handles the default button by changing the definition of `-fx-base`:

```
.button:default {
    -fx-base: -fx-default-button;
}
```

So setting the background to `-fx-base` won't remove the default blue color.

It's not clear quite what you want to achieve, but you are probably needing something like

```
.dialog-pane .button { 
    -fx-background-color: -fx-base; 
    -fx-text-fill: white; 
}

.dialog-pane .button:default {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-default-button;
}
```

and then wherever you are changing `-fx-base` you should also change `-fx-default-button`.

Answer (score 0):

I see my confusion. I was working on an existing stylesheet that was trying to use -fx-base like a variable even though it's the name of an existing attribute.

Comment: It's not an existing attribute. It is an existing "looked-up color" (which you can think of as a variable). If you are using your own looked-up colors, I would strongly recommend not prefixing them `-fx`, so as to avoid conflict with existing ones.